# C++ Simple Encryption

Tags: c++, encryption, character

I read the book "The C++ Programming Language" by Bjarne Stroustrup and one of his exercises was to make a simple encryption. I type something in, read it with std::cin and encrypt it + print the encrypted text to the screen. This is how I did it :

In my *int main()* :

```
std::string read;
std::cin >> read;

encript(read);
```

My function (just a part) :

```
void encript(const std::string& r){

std::string new_r;
for(int i = 0; i <= r.length(); i++)
{
    switch(r[i])
    {
        case 'a':
            new_r += "a_";
            break;
        case 'b':
            new_r += "b_";
            break;
        case 'c':
            new_r += "c_";
            break;
        case 'd':
            new_r += "d_";
            break;
... //goes on this way 
    }
}

std::cout << new_r << std::endl;
```

My question now do I really have to write every single character? I mean these are only the non capital characters. Also there are special characters, numbers etc.

Is there another way to do it?

Comment: If C++11 is ok, `new_r += {r[i], '_'};`. That takes an initializer list (think of array initialization) consisting of the character and an underscore and adds it onto the end of the string.

Comment: You can get the number of a and the calculate the others

Comment: @Bakudan, Except they aren't guaranteed to be contiguous.

Comment: @chris if I do that, every single character becomes '_' , right? So I wont be able to decrypt it?

Comment: Not your question, but this is an error `for(int i = 0; i <= r.length(); i++)`. Should be `for(int i = 0; i < r.length(); i++)`.

Comment: @john huh? why? Then the last character won't be used

Comment: @CGuy, It will do the same as you have. It just makes a group of that character and an underscore and adds the group.

Comment: @CGuy, `str[str.length()]` gives you one past the last character.

Comment: @chris ah, right! stupid me!

Comment: @CGuy. The last character is `r[r.length() - 1]`. Your code has one extra character,

Comment: @CGuy Because arrays and strings are indexed from 0 in C++. 0 is the first character, 1 is the second, 2 is the third, and so on. So if you go up to `r.length()`, you end up going past the end!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this will be the same:

```
void encript(const std::string& r){

std::string new_r;
for(int i = 0; i < r.length(); i++) // change this too
{
    new_r += r[i];
    new_r += "_";
}

std::cout << new_r << std::endl;
```

**but alternatively** you might use just **STL**. Don't have to use C++11:

```
string sentence = "Something in the way she moves...";
istringstream iss(sentence);
ostringstream oss;

copy(istream_iterator<char>(iss),
     istream_iterator<char>(),
     ostream_iterator<char> (oss,"_"));

cout<<oss.str();
```

> output:
>
> S_o_m_e_t_h_i_n_g_i_n_t_h_e_w_a_y_s_h_e_m_o_v_e_s_. _. _. _

Comment: `+=` can take a single character, unlike the constructor, so `new_r += r[i];` works.

Answer (score 4):

There is another way ofcourse:

```
new_r += std::string(1,r[i]) + "_";
```

Answer (score 4):

If you use range-for, it's cleaner:

```
std::string new_r;
for (char c : r) {
    new_r += c;
    new_r += '_';
}
```